# C system() function

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm trying to  create a file in linux and give it executable rights using `system()` function in a C program. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
char s[100];
strcpy(s, "touch ");
strcpy(s, argv[1]);
strcpy(s, "; chmod a+x ");
strcpy(s, argv[1]);
system(s);
return 0;
}
```

But when I call compiled file with argument "abs" for example (consider I want "abs" as the name of the file to be created) it gives such output:

```
sh: 1: abs: not found
```

How can it be fixed? It's important that I have to use C programming and `system()` function.

Comment: You should research the difference between `strcpy` and `strcat` or use `sprintf` to construct the argument all at once. Consider using a debugger to examine `s` as each line of code executes or use `printf` to print it out.

Comment: Add `printf("s = \"%s\"\n", s);` right before `system(s);` and you'll uderstand what's going on. Be curious.

Comment: I recommend not using [system(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) (if required to use it, be careful about your `$PATH`) but system calls like [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [chmod(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) and others listed in [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: You probably should run `./abs` if your C source code was named `abs.c`. See [bash(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) and [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and read the documentation of your shell (probably [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)). It is open source and you are allowed to download its source code and study it. Compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: And your program would fail if invoked with a single argument containing a space (or even worse, like a long string such as `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_0123456789` ....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that answer is not understandable for future readers, let me try to explain what is the difference between **strcpy** and **strcat**

- **strcpy()** copies one string into another.
- **strcat()** function concatenates string by appending source string to destination string.

In the original code, every time a "**strcpy**" function was called, a previous value in the buffer was overwritten.

```
char s[100];
strcpy(s, "touch "); // s = touch
strcpy(s, argv[1]); // s = abc (argv[1] value)
strcpy(s, "; chmod a+x "); // s = ; chmod a+x 
strcpy(s, argv[1]); // s = abc (argv[1] value)
system(s); // execute s = abc
```

And finally, since "**s**" is "**abc**" system() function tries to execute it, which is producing the following error:

```
sh: 1: abs: not found
```

In the modified version, instead of overwriting the previous value, the new value is appended to the buffer.

```
char s[100];
strcpy(s, "touch "); // s = touch
strcat(s, argv[1]); // s = touch abc
strcat(s, "; chmod a+x "); // s = touch abc; chmod a+x
strcat(s, argv[1]); // s = touch abc; chmod a+x abc
system(s); // execute s = touch abc; chmod a+x abc
```

Comment: "overriding" -> "overwriting"

Answer (score 0):

**strcpy** copies a string to another, use strncat (3) to concatenate strings.

Your code should be like that:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) sizeof(X)/sizeof(X[0])

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
    char s[100];
    strncat(s, "touch ", ARRAY_SIZE(s) - 1 - strlen(s));
    strncat(s, argv[1], ARRAY_SIZE(s) - 1 - strlen(s));
    strncat(s, "; chmod a+x ", ARRAY_SIZE(s) - 1 - strlen(s));
    strncat(s, argv[1], ARRAY_SIZE(s) - 1 - strlen(s));
    system(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code should be changed to the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
char s[100];
strcpy(s, "touch "); //s = "touch "
strcat(s, argv[1]); //s = "touch " + argv[1]
strcat(s, "; chmod a+x "); //s = "touch " + argv[1] + "; chmod a+x " 
strcat(s, argv[1]); //s =  "touch " + argv[1] + "; chmod a+x " + argv[1]
system(s); //system("touch " + argv[1] + "; chmod a+x " + argv[1])
return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot to commentators!

Comment: If you give an answer to a question. Be it someone's other question, or yours, you should give a proper answer. So others could benefit from the information. Posting a code without an explanation does not give an insight about how the problem was solved.